# Regex 2 letters and 3, 4 or 5 digits

Tags: sql-server

Can I do a regex in a SP in SQL Server and catch part of a string than contains 2 letters and 3, 4 or 5 digits?

The string can be like this:

```
"Joe Brown AB12345 21223355"
```

or

```
"Joe Brown AB1234 21223355"
```

or

```
"Joe Brown AB123 21223355"
```

And I want to find AB12345, AB1234, AB123

I have tried with this:

```
SUBSTRING(Name, (PATINDEX('%[A-Za-z][A-Za-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',[Name])),7)
```

Comment: Will there always be a space separator?

Comment: Consider alternative universes: A) This would be simple in app code, B) If it’s important info, it deserves its own column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use string_split().

Note the last two OR's may not be necessary, just more precise.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([SomeCol] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('Joe Brown AB12345 21223355')
,('Joe Brown AB1234 21223355')
,('Joe Brown AB123 21223355')

Select * 
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply string_split(SomeCol,' ') B
 Where B.value like '[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
    or B.value like '[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
    or B.value like '[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

**Returns**

```
SomeCol                     value
Joe Brown AB12345 21223355  AB12345
Joe Brown AB1234 21223355   AB1234
Joe Brown AB123 21223355    AB123
```

Comment: Actually, you could argue that the middle `or` is entirely redundant even if you want the first and last.

Comment: @shawnt00 I agree, but AB123Z may not be desired

Comment: Yeah, you're using `split()`. I was thinking about my approach.

Comment: I suppose if you wanted something generic you could do something like  Where B.value like '[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9]%' and not B.value like '%[0-9]%[A-Z]%'.  In case there were outlier values fitting the pattern that you wanted to catch.

Comment: @JJ32 Good alternative as well.   Can't imagine a performance boost, but worth a try.

Comment: Agreed, if your project requirements are strictly defined best to go with what matches exactly

Answer (score 0):

Not the prettiest, but should work...

```
declare @s varchar(32) = 'select [NAME] from ...';
select case
    when patindex('%[A-Za-z][A-Za-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', @s) > 0
    then substring(@s, patindex('%[A-Za-z][A-Za-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', @s), 7)
    when patindex('%[A-Za-z][A-Za-z][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', @s) > 0
    then substring(@s, patindex('%[A-Za-z][A-Za-z][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', @s), 6)
    when patindex('%[A-Za-z][A-Za-z][0-9][0-9]%', @s) > 0
    then substring(@s, patindex('%[A-Za-z][A-Za-z][0-9][0-9]%', @s), 5)
end
```